# Headless Chrome Navigate to Page, click to linked page, then printToPDF

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome-devtools, google-chrome-headless

I have to print all HTML pages linked to from a product information page:
http://prod.adv-bio.com/ProductDetail.aspx?ProdNo=1197

I have set up a test script to see if I could do this for just one of the HTML files. I used PyChromeDevTools and Selenium, hoping I could use the printToPDF function in DevTools while using Selenium to click the links I need to click.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
import requests
import time
import re
import websocket
import PyChromeDevTools
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options


chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--remote-debugging-port=9222')
chrome_options.add_argument('--window-size=1200x600')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')




driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\\Users\\me\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36-    32\\selenium\\webdriver\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe',         chrome_options = chrome_options)
driver.get("http://prod.adv-bio.com/ProductDetail.aspx?ProdNo=1197")

browser = PyChromeDevTools.ChromeInterface()
browser.Network.enable()
browser.Page.enable()
driver.implicitly_wait(20)                                                                 



driver.get("http://prod.adv-bio.com/ProductDetail.aspx?ProdNo=1197")
time.sleep(3)
url = driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text("Continuing")
time.sleep(3)
ActionChains(driver).click(url).perform()
time.sleep(3)


Page.printToPDF()

time.sleep(5)
```

and I am getting this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\me\SOtestfile.py", line 29, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\\Python27\\Lib\\site-
packages\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe', chrome_options = 
chromeOptions, desired_capabilities=capabilities)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 69, in __init__
desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 98, in __init__
    self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 188, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 256, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 194, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
WebDriverException: Message: chrome not reachable
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.31.488763 (092de99f48a300323ecf8c2a4e2e7cab51de5ba8),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64)
```

I have updated chromedriver to 2.31 and have chrome version 60, should I be using canary? I appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 0):

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import 
DesiredCapabilities    

chromeOptions = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chromeOptions.add_argument("headless")
chromeOptions.add_argument("window-size=1366,768")

capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME.copy()
capabilities["browserName"] = "chrome"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chromeOptions,
desired_capabilities=capabilities)
```

Worked here!! (Chrome 60 + Chromedriver 2.31) Hope this helps!!

Comment: I just tried editing the code I posted to use these options, but now get an error. Were you able to print the file to pdf? Would you mind posting the rest of the code you used? I'm starting to think it's a problem with my proxy, or that PyChromeDevTools and Selenium use the same port and can't be run together.

Comment: Try to comment these two lines in your code: `chrome_options.add_argument('--remote-debugging-port=9222')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')`

Comment: Unfortunately commenting those out didn't solve my problem. I am going to try to replicate this on my personal computer next and rule out whether my work firewall is getting in the way. I was able to get this to work with FireFox, but the firewall forces me to log in every loop(IT strongly encourages IE but I bet none of them use it...) I will post my questions/gratitude when finished.